# JHipster problem with frontend/gateway communication

Tags: jhipster, csrf-protection, csrf-token

following [the explanation on separating frontend and gateway](https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/), I created two JHipster applications:

- Gateway using *jhipster --skip-client*
- Frontend using *jhipster --skip-server --db --auth uaa --uaa-base-name uaa-server*

When using Swagger-UI, I can use the default API and the API of my UAA server. I can also see in the drop-down menu my micro-services but when selecting them, I get an error message :

> Can't read swagger JSON from http://127.0.0.1:9000/myservice/v2/api-docs

What is wrong in my configuration ? What did I forget ?

[EDIT] I finally found, see below

**The second question** is about the communication between frontend and gateway when both are running on different machines.
Authentication seems to be correct when looking at UAA server but frontend side receives a 403 code. It seems to be a problem with CSRF but I don't know how to handle it.
What's the way to deal with CSRF in JHipster ?

PS : I'm pretty sure I will also have problem when making to microservices talk together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added contexts for proxying in webpack.dev.js and it seems to be working.